# Why am I getting an unexpected `0xcc` byte when loading nearby code bytes? Is it because of segment register %es?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, segment

I got some inconsistent result of instruction.
I don't know why this happens, so I suspect `%es` register is doing something weird, but I'm not sure.

Look at below code snippet.

```
08048400 <main>:
 8048400:   bf 10 84 04 08          mov    $HERE,%edi     
 8048405:   26 8b 07                mov    %es:(%edi),%eax  # <----- Result 1
 8048408:   bf 00 84 04 08          mov    $main,%edi
 804840d:   26 8b 07                mov    %es:(%edi),%eax  # <----- Result 2

08048410 <HERE>:
 8048410:   11 11                   adc    %edx,(%ecx)
 8048412:   11 11                   adc    %edx,(%ecx)
```

***Result 1:***

```
%eax : 0x11111111
```

Seeing this result, I guessed that   `mov %es:(%edi),%eax` to be something like `mov (%edi),%eax`.
Because `0x11111111` is stored at `HERE`.

***Result 2:***

```
%eax : 0x048410cc
```

However, the result of **Result 2** was quite different.
I assumed %eax to be `0x048410bf`, because this value is stored at `main`.
But the result was different as you can see.


***Question:***
Why this inconsistency of the result happens?
By the way, value of `%es` was always 0x7b during execution of both instruction.

Comment: If you're running this under any mainstream OS like Linux or Windows, you'll have a flat memory model where the ES segment base is 0, same as CS, DS, and SS.  (FS or GS are typically used for thread-local storage).  The actual ES *value* is a segment selector that indexes into the GDT.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh.. Because of base of `%es` is always 0, then `%es:(%edi)` would always be `0:(%edi)`? If yes, why compiler use this `%es` register to represent `0`?

Comment: We don't know what source you compiled.

Comment: @Jiwon: Where did you get this asm?  It looks super weird.  I assumed you wrote it yourself by hand.  But anyway, no, the assembler doesn't *know* the ES segment base is the same as the DS segment base unless you're assembling 64-bit code (where the segment bases *are* fixed at 0, except FS/GS).  The assembler can't make assumptions about the machine state this code will run under.  It's up to the C compiler (or human programmer) to make such optimizations and not use prefixes where they'll have no effect in the conditions you expect your code to run in.  (i.e. under a normal OS.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`es` is a red herring. The difference you see is 1 byte at `main`, `cc` vs. `bf`. That is because you used a software breakpoint at `main` and your debugger inserted an `int3` instruction which has machine code `cc` temporarily overwriting your actual code.

Do not set a breakpoint where you intend to read from, or use a hardware breakpoint instead which does not modify code.

Comment: Wow I didn't even suspect breakpoint to be the cause... Thank you, I've learned something new !