# How does GDB set a breakpoint for a given instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, x86-64

I've read alot about how INT 3 creates a sigtrap but I'm not sure how it could be inserted to trigger a breakpoint without affecting the code.

Comment: It can't be. It is inserted overwriting code, but the debugger remembers the original byte and restores it as appropriate. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54573237/547981) about how that can cause problems.

Comment: [How debuggers work: Breakpoints](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/27/how-debuggers-work-part-2-breakpoints)

Comment: Thanks alot, these are great resources. Feel free to put an answer up so I can mark this as answered.

Comment: by definition setting a breakpoint affects the code. it stops it...

Comment: @old_timer, true, but a hardware breakpoint does it without *modifying* the code.

Comment: okay code itself vs execution, fair enough.   there are two basic flavors of breakpoint, one is modify the instruction the other is some architectures and implementations have on chip debuggers such that you can stop execution without modifying the instruction.  and some debuggers choose one or the other depending on what choices are available.